# Где можно захостить Spring Boot проект?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Здравствуйте. Есть небольшой учебный проект на Spring Boot с БД mysql.
Мне нужно его захостить хотя бы на месяц. Только я не имею представление, как это делать. Я, вроде как знаю, что нужно доменное имя покупать(только не знаю где), и где в мире сервер найти для java.

```
applecation.properties

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/auth
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = testbd
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.default_schema=app_audit
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>auth</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Restaurant</name>
    <description>Restaurant</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <start-class>com.spring.AuthApplication</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите вот здесь. Это размещение на Jelastic, однако, это может Вам дать дополнительную информацию и понимание, что делать. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43328762/how-to-host-spring-boot-application-with-postgresql-on-the-could-jelastic/43370194#43370194

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте бесплатный, для ваших нужд, сервис [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/)

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас начну бороться с heroku)

Comment: Там не сложно, есть кучу гайдов по настройке и использованию. Ну а если не получится обращайтесь постараемся ответить!

Comment: Блин да тут пот и слёзы). Куча гайдов и не все какие то непонятные. Как лучше задеплоить пытаться? Как jar или я попробывал deploy branch с github оно вроде скомпилило на при первом же входе падает. Читал но не понял это вроде какая то ошибка pom.xml. А з базой установил clearDB Mysql вроде как дали URL но не могу понять как его в конфиги засунуть)

Comment: |@ЮлийЩербак Лучше это конечно с гита тянуть, там есть еще какой то конфиг файл специально для хероку `java $JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active="heroku" -DTOPJAVA_ROOT="." -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war` так он выглядит в моем случае. Когда падает, что в логах пишет? Там есть урл и креденшиалы пробуйте сначала просто через IDE подключится потом уже суйте в конфиги

Comment: Чудо это запустилось) Но теперь осталось с базой розобраться. Вроде в конфигах я правильно ввёл url. но как быть с таблицами? Указать чтоб гибернэйт их при старте создал и как их заполнить?

Comment: @ЮлийЩербак Скриптом. Подключитесь к базе при помощи той же IntelijIDEA точно также как к локальной базе, и выполните скрипты по созданию и заполнению базы.

Comment: |@Victor В чём может быть проблема что страничек некоторых не видит? Tempalate not found

Comment: Так сказать сложно. Оформите новым вопросом с приложеным кодом проекта

Comment: |@Victor Что именно нужно выложить проект просто не маленький.

Comment: Структуру проекта конфигурацию спринга и пом

Comment: |@Victor Добавил что просили, только не уверен что под структурой проекта правильно понял)

Comment: Структура: правильно только желательно вплоть до страниц которых не видно. Я имел ввиду оформить новым вопросом. Потому как текущий вопрос себя исчерпал и заголовок никак не отражает вашу новую проблему. Подсказать я возможно и не подскажу. а знающие люди не зайдут просто в этот вопрос потому что он про хостинг

Comment: |@Victor http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/640012

Answer (score -2):

Есть два хороших ресурса:

1. [archacloud.com](http://archacloud.com)
2. [herocu.com](http://herocu.com)

Я больше предпочитаю 1 вариант, так как был более выгодным и простым в эксплуатации. Но на вкус товарища нужно поискать)

Comment: Вы если и даете ссылки на сторонние ресурсы, пожалуйста проверяйте их работоспособность!

Comment: Извеняюсь за очепятки.