# Spring Boot Heroku не отображает некоторые страницы

Tags: spring-boot, heroku

Захостил проект на heroku. Запустил его но почему при переходе на некоторые странички ошибка Error resolving template "/waiter/order_check", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers.
К примеру 
Контроллер

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/order/{id}/close", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String closeOrder(@PathVariable("id") long id,
                             Model model) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd ' ' HH:mm:ss");
        User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        model.addAttribute("order", orderService.getCheckInfo(id));
        model.addAttribute("details", orderDetailService.getOrderDetails(id));
        model.addAttribute("closedDate", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
        model.addAttribute("waiter", user.getUsername());
        orderService.closeOrder(id);
        return "/waiter/order_check";
    }
```

Страничка

```
<div th:replace="fragments :: head"></div>


<body>
<div th:replace="fragments :: navbar"></div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-centered">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <button class="btn btn-danger dropp">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i> Print check
            </button>
            <h3 align="center" th:text="${order.creationDate} + ' - ' + ${closedDate}"></h3>
            <h1 align="center" th:text="'Order№' + ${order.orderNumber}"></h1>
            <p class="text-left" th:text="${order.floorName} + ', Table№' + ${order.tableNumber}"></p>
            <p class="text-left" th:text="'Served by ' + ${waiter}"></p>
            <table class="table table-condensed">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Count</th>
                    <th>Sum</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr th:each="detail : ${details}">
                    <td th:text="${detail.prod_category} + ' ' + ${detail.prod_name}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${detail.count}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${detail.sum}"></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="right">Discount amount</td>
                    <td th:text="${order.discountAmount}"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="right">Total amount</td>
                    <td th:text="${order.totalAmount}"></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <h2 align="center">Thank you for your visit!</h2>
            <h2 align="center">We will be glad to see you again</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-shadow"></div>
<div class="modal-window" style="width: 499px; height: 354px;">
    <div class="close">X</div>
    <img th:src="@{/images/cat.jpg}" class="img-rounded" />
</div>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.dropp').click(function () {
            $('.modal-shadow').show();
            $('.modal-window').show();
        });

        $('.modal-shadow').click(function () {
            $('.modal-shadow').hide();
            $('.modal-window').hide();
        });

        $('.close').click(function () {
            $('.modal-shadow').hide();
            $('.modal-window').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>auth</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Restaurant</name>
    <description>Restaurant</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <start-class>com.spring.AuthApplication</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

properties

```
 spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/auth
    spring.datasource.username = root
    spring.datasource.password = testbd
    spring.jpa.show-sql = true
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
    spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.default_schema=app_audit
```

Answer (score 1):

Все я нашёл ошибку. По неизвестным причинам если в контроллере стоит слеш перед возвращаемой страничкой `return "/waiter/order_check";` Heroku не находил её. Хотя на компьютере всё работало и так.